# Viewing SV testbench tasks,signal names in Modelsim

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I want to view in Modelsim SV driver signals, tasks to debug. I don't want to add display statements everywhere to know how my test is progressing.Please let me know if there is a way we can do it. I tried adding the signals from simulation but when I restart the simulation the tool hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$display` and (for UVM) `uvm_info` statements are the most common ways of debugging signals that reside inside functions and tasks.  ModelSim/Questa have the ability to add signals from inside a `uvm_component` to a waveform, but not transient signals that exist only inside a function or task.  One trick I do to view them inside the waveform or log is to create an observe signal outside the function/task that I assign the value that I want to observe whenever the task is called.